# Moving a texture

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I have a texture pack that modifies the shield to a captain America shield, and I have a texture pack that modifies the look of the trident. Is there ANY way that I can make the shield texture pack apply to the trident instead of the shield? I want to make a trident look like the captain america shield

Comment: this question shows that you did little research

Comment: @Topcode I think it's fair, changing models can be confusing for a beginner

Comment: This 4-video series will explain a lot of your questions. It mainly explains how to make a functional resource pack, with new models and textures, Using Blockbench. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IstDgCq-xuc